# Implementing a custom QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler, cannot reply with a QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwebengine, qtnetwork

Using Qt 5.8, we are setting to implement a custom `QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler`. Its behaviour should be to issue a `GET` query and respond with the returned content.

Our understanding is that the content is returned to the web engine through [`QWebEngineUrlRequestJob::reply`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestjob.html#reply) second argument, which should derive from `QIODevice`. And as [`QNetworkReply`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html) derives from it, we expected an instance of this type to be a valid content provider.

A minimal example (not concerned with freeing dynamically allocated memory) would be:

```
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QWebEngineUrlRequestJob>
#include <QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler>

class CustomHandler : public QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *aRequestJob) override
    {
        QUrl requestedUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest(requestedUrl);
        QNetworkReply *reply = mManager.get(*request);

        connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
                this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

        // Reply segment
        aRequestJob->reply("text/html", reply);
    }

public slots:
    void slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError aError)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: "  <<  aError << std::endl;
    }

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager mManager;
};
```

When executed, this outputs:

```
Error: 5
```

The code thus fails by calling the error slot `CustomHandler::slotError` with `QNetworkReply::NetworkError`, [which corresponds to a canceled operation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qnetworkreply.html#NetworkError-enum).

---

Is there a way to reply with a `QNetworkReply`, or is it mandatory to wait for the request to complete and then extract its reply content into a `QBuffer` first?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it should work the way you coded it, but in practice it worked reliably for me only when `aRequestJob->reply("text/html", reply);` was called from the `QNetworkReply::finished` signal. You can also try to use `readyRead` signal, then you have to call `reply` every time you receive the signal, but as far as I remember it wasn't very reliable, so I decided to stick with the `finished` signal.

You can also move the data to `QBuffer` upon `finished`, but for any reason you have to `close()` the buffer before replying with it, otherwise it is not get read and appears as an empty response.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this [QTBUG-106461](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-106461) 5 days ago. The fixes are already merged into Qt *dev* branch and cherry-picked into several release branches. The example code in this question description should work in Qt WebEngine 6.4.1 or later.

It is unfortunate that developers choose to discuss bugs on StackOverflow and forums, apply workarounds and forget, instead of reporting them upstream. This bug could have been fixed long ago.

Answer (score -1):

to avoid this error you have to insert

```
reply.deleteLater()
```

But in my case I don't see any result displayed. Don't know what to do get this working with QNetworkReply

Comment: Bad advice, this will delete the reply once Qt enters the event loop, but the docs [say the contrary](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlrequestjob.html#reply), that it must stay available until the job is completed.